# Interfacing 2 accelerometers through I2C

Tags: i2c, microprocessor

I am looking at designing a system where 2 accelerometers are connected to a microcontroller using I2C however I am unsure as to how this would actually work. In particular would I need a microcontroller with 2 I2C interfaces or would it be possible to connect them both via the one interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic functionality of I2C allows multiple slave devices connected to and communicating with a master (or more than one master) device. Each slave device must have a different address. This can be a problem with some devices that allow only a limited selection of slave addresses or even a single, unchangable address. (There are work arounds with bus multiplexors and such.)

Summary: yes, you can probably put two accelerometers on a single bus, but it depends on the specific device selected.

I'd suggest that you do basic reading on I2C before proceeding with your project.

Comment: If you can't use accelerometer that has address selection you have this options: 1) Some microcontrolers have two I²C ports, so you can use two devices that are the same. 2) use an I²C hub, I²C hubs have multiple I²C ports allowing you to connect multiple I²C devices with the same address.